# Some functions stop work after publish

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

i encounter some problems, when i'm publishing my website, because after publish some functions stop working, e.g. i have two linkbuttons, and one of them is not visible, or application stop sending mails, skins aren't loaded correctly. Application is a little modification of DotNetNuke, i tried to deal with it, but i have no idea what is the source of this problem and where look for solution.

Comment: And everything works fine, when you start the app in Debug Mode?
Maybe your web.config is not configured correctly?

Comment: Yes, when i deploy sources to the server, every functionality works fine - until publish. But what could be a problem in web.config? Some functions stop working, one time mailing, other works fine and after another - registration stops working.

Comment: Are you publishing from Visual Studio? I don't recommend you "publish" anything from VS for a live DNN website. If you're doing custom module development you should be creating installable modules. If you're just "setting up" the website, then manually backup/restore your site into production.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the file locations for support files to be sure they are correct for the server. Also use firebug to see if you can determine what is missing or happening when you load the file / page on the live server or drop some alerts in the offending code to see if they pop on the page.